# GCS Transfer via Source: URL list "errorCode": "UNKNOWN"

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to transfer 7,860,379 files, using the transfer system via URL list, however always encounter the same error:

```
   { //...
     "errorBreakdowns": [
     {
      "errorCode": "UNKNOWN",
      "errorCount": "1",
      "errorLogEntries": [
       {
        "url": " or ",
        "errorDetails": [
         ""
        ]
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
    // ...
   }
```

All the my URLs are valid and the file format as documented:

```
TsvHttpData-1.0
^([^ ]+)\t([0-9]+)\t([a-f0-9]{32})$
```

The error I find the API is very generic, someone went through the same problem?

Since, I thank you.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-url-list#creating_the_url_list

Answer (score 1):

Based on your regex, I suspect you are not providing a base-64 encoded MD5, as it often contains '=' characters. To do this, you need to compute the binary version of your MD5 and then convert it to base64.

Example: Hk2gdsIpWTDz3kQssoTqKg==